# How can I modify the style of one mat-select but not affect others on the same page without global css？

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

Scoped styles cannot affect mat-select (the finally generated elements doesn't have property of the component-id).

I tried to add component-name and the style class name to the mat-select like

`<mat-select [panelClass]="'component-name logger'">`

and add style in `style.css` in angular project's root dir so it will affect globally.

```css
.component-name.logger {
    max-width: 700px;
}
```

But it's forbidden to use global styles now, How can I modify one mat-select without affecting other mat-select?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: if you don't want to use global styles then you could put the style in the stylesheet in your component.

Comment: put the style in the stylesheet in your component will become scoped styles, but the elements generated from mat-select does't have the component-id, so it won't work. @MikePoole

Comment: I don't think that's the case, but then again I don't think using the global stylesheet is "forbidden" either.